# d3 dendogram, is there a way to make a single node standout?

Tags: d3.js

I am using this exact code into our website (code is at the bottom of the webpage)

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570

I am wondering if there is a way to add a json attribute to send back and modify the javascript such that one node is much much more bold than all the other nodes(perhaps a bigger circle or bigger bold font) such that it is obvious that this is the selected node.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of the nodes is controlled through the respective CSS and the code

```
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5);
```

You can add arbitrary attributes to the JSON and check them there, e.g.

```
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.selected ? 10 : 4.5; });
```

It works similarly for the font.